# scala: select column where not contains elements into dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have this ligne of code that should create a dataframe from list of columns that not contain a string. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
val exemple = hiveObj.sql("show tables in database").select("tableName")!==="ABC".collect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the filter method:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._
val exemple = hiveObj.sql("your query here").filter($"columnToFilter" =!= "ABC").show
```

**NOTE:** the inequality operator `=!=`is only available for Spark 2.0.0+. If you're using an older version, you must use `!==`. You can see the documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.Column).

If you need to filter several columns you can do so:

```
.filter($"columnToFilter" =!= "ABC" and $"columnToFilter2" =!= "ABC")
```

Comment: `filtre  ..org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (Boolean)
       val exemple = hiveObj.sql("show tables in database").filter($"tableName" == "ABC").show()`

Comment: You need to select a table. If I've understood correctly your question, you want to filter columns from a Hive table. Why don't you execute `select * from database.tableName`?

Comment: "TableName"  here refers to column not to a table

Comment: Ok, I guess I know what's happening. The compare operator to check if two columns are equal is `===`, not `==`. And remember, you need to import the spark implicits `import spark.implicits._` to use the `$`column selector.

Comment: but how to make the opposite case: not contains

Comment: I've specified that in my answer. Use the `=!=` operator.

Comment: `value =!= is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName`

Comment: `=!=` should work. Try instead `!==`. What Spark version are you using?

Comment: Yes, this is what I would say, Thanks

Comment: Great! Can you accept my answer if it helped, please?

Comment: update your answer and make sure that you have put the both version =!= and !==

Answer (score 0):

another alternative answer to my question:

```
val exemple1 = hiveObj.sql("show tables in database").filter(!$"tableName".contains("ABC")).show()
```